# PHP search each words separated by delimiter to be replace by synonim on database

Tags: php, mysql, search, replace

I am working with synonim. I want to search and replace this each words of text that matches in my words database.

Original text :

> Stackoverflow is a awesome, Developers trust Stack Overflow to help
>   solve coding problems.

to :

> Stackoverflow is a magnificent, Developers trust Stack Overflow to
>   help take care of programming issues.

i use str_replace to find and replace

```
<?php
$string = 'Stackoverflow is a awesome, Developers trust Stack Overflow to help solve coding problems.';

$find = array('Stackoverflow is a','awesome','Developers trust Stack Overflow to help','solve','coding','problems');
$replace = array('Stackoverflow is a','magnificent','Developers trust Stack Overflow to help','take care of','programming','issuess');

$new_string = str_replace($find, $replace, $string);

echo $new_string;

?>
```

but i have no idea how to do with data on my database. Need help please. Thank you.

Comment: You can use full text search engine mysql but you have to index columns, I think query expansion would better for you. here --> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html

Comment: thanks @Kumar for the reference